# docker-compose healthcheck retry frequency != interval

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-check

I recently set up `healthcheck`s in my `docker-compose` config.

It is doing great and I like it. Here's a typical example:

```
services:
  app:
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -sS http://127.0.0.1:4000 || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
```

My container is quite slow to boot, hence I set up a 30 seconds `start_period`.

But it doesn't really fit my expectation: I don't need check every 5 seconds, but I need to know when the container is ready for the first time as soon as possible for my orchestration, and since my `start_period` is approximative, if it is not ready yet at first check, I have to wait for `interval` before retry.

What I'd like to have is:

- While container is not healthy, retry every 5 seconds
- Once it is healthy, check every 1 minute

Ain't there a way to achieve this out-of-the-box with `docker-compose`?

I could write a custom script to achieve this, but I'd rather have a native solution if it is possible.

Comment: there is no such service out-of-the-box, you need to achieve that using the test script, or wait-for-it.sh

Comment: There is a new option `start_interval` in Docker 25 (not released yet). See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10830.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible out of the box.
All the duration set are final. They can't be changed depending on the container state.

However, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck), the probe does not seem to wait for the `start_period` to finish before checking your test. The only thing it does is that any failure hapenning during `start_period` will not be considered as an error.

Below is the sentence that make me think that :

> `start_period` provides initialization time for containers that need time to bootstrap. **Probe failure during that period will not be counted towards the maximum number of retries.** However, if a health check succeeds during the start period, the container is considered started and all consecutive failures will be counted towards the maximum number of retries.

I encourage you to test if this is really the case as I've never really paid any attention if the healthcheck is tested during the start period or not.
And if it is the case, you can probably increase your `start_period` if you're unsure about the duration and also increase the `interval` in order to find a good compromise.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script that does this, though I'd rather find a native solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

HEALTHCHECK_FILE="/root/.healthchecked"

COMMAND=${*?"Usage: healthcheck_retry <COMMAND>"}

if [ -r "$HEALTHCHECK_FILE" ]; then
  LAST_HEALTHCHECK=$(date -r "$HEALTHCHECK_FILE" +%s)
  # FIVE_MINUTES_AGO=$(date -d 'now - 5 minutes' +%s)
  FIVE_MINUTES_AGO=$(echo "$(( $(date +%s)-5*60 ))")
  echo "Healthcheck file present";
  # if (( $LAST_HEALTHCHECK > $FIVE_MINUTES_AGO )); then
  if [ $LAST_HEALTHCHECK -gt $FIVE_MINUTES_AGO ]; then
    echo "Healthcheck too recent";
    exit 0;
  fi
fi

if $COMMAND ; then
  echo "\"$COMMAND\" succeed: updating file";
  touch $HEALTHCHECK_FILE;
  exit 0;
else
  echo "\"$COMMAND\" failed: exiting";
  exit 1;
fi
```

Which I use: `test: /healthcheck_retry.sh curl -fsS localhost:4000/healthcheck`

The pain is that I need to make sure the script is available in *every* container, so I have to create an extra volume for this:

```
    image: postgres:11.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/utils/healthcheck_retry.sh:/healthcheck_retry.sh
```